# Filter a pyspark.RDD with regex

Tags: python, apache-spark, date, pyspark, rdd

I have a pyspark.RDD containing dates that I would like to filter out. The dates appear in such form within my RDD:

`data.collect() = ["Nujabes","Hip Hop","04:45 16 October 2018"]`

I have been trying to filter these out through a regex using:

```
r"[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2} [A-Z][a-z]+ [0-9]{4}"
```

but I am doing it the wrong way:

```
data = data.filter(lambda x: x != r"[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2} [A-Z][a-z]+ [0-9]{4}")
```

For the given `data` above, the desired output would be

```
data.collect() = ["Nujabes","Hip Hop"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter with Python regex:

```
data2 = data.filter(lambda x: not re.match(r"[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2} [A-Z][a-z]+ [0-9]{4}", x))
```